# Spring Data MongoDB Lifecycle events: is it possible to always handle them synchronously?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use Spring Data MongoDB lifecycle events to compute a field 'after save' based on the ID that was generated by MongoDB when inserting. [Reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events) says the following about a different event, 'before save':

> To intercept an object before it goes into the database, you can register a subclass of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener that overrides the onBeforeSave method. When the event is dispatched, your listener is called and passed the domain object and the converted com.mongodb.Document. The following example shows how to do so:

Then they provide an example.

I did something similar for 'after save':

```
public class MyMongoDbLifecycleListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<MyModel> {
    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<MyModel> event) {
        super.onAfterSave(event);

        MyModel model = event.getSource();

        model.computeValueFromTheAssignedId();
    }
}
```

This works in tests, but in pre-production testing we stumbled upon a problem: sometimes (actually, quite often) the value is not precomputed to the moment when the object is returned from a `Repository`'s `save()` method.

The problem is that application events are processed asynchronously in our application. We have the following in our configuration:

```
<bean id="simpleAsyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
     ...
</bean>
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster" class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="simpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    ...
</bean>
```

In `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` there is the following code that actually does the multicasting:

```
public void multicastEvent(final ApplicationEvent event, @Nullable ResolvableType eventType) {
    ResolvableType type = (eventType != null ? eventType : resolveDefaultEventType(event));
    for (final ApplicationListener<?> listener : getApplicationListeners(event, type)) {
        Executor executor = getTaskExecutor();
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.execute(() -> invokeListener(listener, event));
        }
        else {
            invokeListener(listener, event);
        }
    }
}
```

So our application context multicasts **all** events asynchronously and invokes the listeners in a thread that is different from the thread in which we call `save()`, so we have no guarantee to see the effect of a listener after the save.

I'm confused. The documentation wording ('To intercept an object before ...') clearly indicates that this happens **strictly before** convertion/save/whatever. But a simple (and natural) configuration change breaks these guarantees. I suspect I do something wrong, but how should I do it correctly?

The only idea I have now is to write an extension of a multicaster that would specifically handle all MongoDB-related events synchronously. That should work, but should it be so easy to break a system behavior?

Comment: I am giving a wild guess, but maybe the objects are not stored yet in the database if you are in a transaction, and the events are propagating after calling save but before the actual commit.

Comment: Thank you @Mihai but we don't use transactions. And the events are actually handled in another thread without any external synchronization applied, so there is no way to guarantee the order (I debugged this through the code).

Answer (score 1):

Here is `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` extension that allows to achieve 'sync handling for spring-data-mongodb events' policy:

```
public class SystemEventsAreSyncronousMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {
    @Override
    public void multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent event, ResolvableType eventType) {
        ResolvableType type = (eventType != null ? eventType : resolveDefaultEventType(event));
        for (final ApplicationListener<?> listener : getApplicationListeners(event, type)) {
            Executor executor = getTaskExecutor();
            if (executor == null || eventMustBeProcessedSynchronously(event)) {
                invokeListener(listener, event);
            } else {
                executor.execute(() -> invokeListener(listener, event));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean eventMustBeProcessedSynchronously(ApplicationEvent event) {
        return event instanceof MongoMappingEvent;
    }

    private ResolvableType resolveDefaultEventType(ApplicationEvent event) {
        return ResolvableType.forInstance(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need execution ordering guarantees, a more suitable mechanism is `EntityCallback`s: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks

They do not rely on application event publishing, and they do guarantee that a 'before-load' callback will be called before loading.

For the example presented in the original question, this is how it would look like using entity callbacks:

```
public class MyMongoDbLifecycleCallbacks implements AfterSaveCallback<MyModel> {
    @Override
    public MyModel onAfterSave(MyModel entity, Document document, String collection) {
        entity.computeValueFromTheAssignedId();
        return entity;
    }
}
```